# Does Typescript only include approved ECMAScript features?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that Typescript is a superscript of Javascript. Does it include only the features of ECMAScript that are approved? To my understanding, ECMAScript receives a lot of proposals of features to be included and it only approves relatively few of them. Does typescript include only those approved, or does it include implementations of other proposals that are not approved as well?

Also does typescript includes functionality of its own that are not part of ECMAScript at all?

I used typescript to develop Angular applications but do not possess an indepth understanding of it.

Comment: a superset, not a superscript. the very definition of "superset" means that it has everything javascript has, plus more stuff. the "more stuff" may or may not include things that have been proposed to be included in ecmascript. typescript is a microsoft product so ultimately they add whatever they want.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ecmascript+proposal+stages&oq=ecmascript+proposal+stages&aqs=chrome.0.0l2.3080j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 I believe TS goes as far as including (some) stage 3 proposals

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce.: this is a rather nice pun.

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html, particularly the "target=ESNext" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good list of things in TS that are not in ES6 here:

[Which Typescript Features are Not Implemented in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889670/which-typescript-features-are-not-implemented-in-es6)

Just for two examples:

Decorators are an ES next proposal that are currently implemented in TypeScript.

On the other hand, abstract classes were an ES6 proposal that was dropped.  They are not currently an ES7 proposal.

TS is its own standards body essentially.  They can adopt what features they like (e.g. abstract classes) but then are on the hook for maintaining them or making tons of people that rely on them angry.  As such, I would be surprised if TS deviated from ES7 too wildly.